# Ignore deleting specific entity on cascade delete

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following entity:

```
public class ShoppingCartItem
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ShoppingCartItemId { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }    
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string ShoppingCartId { get; set; }
    public DateTime ItemAddedToCart { get; set; } 
}
```

There is a one to one foreign key relationship from `Product` to `ShoppingCartItem`.
My question is, how can I make entity framework core skip deleting the `ShoppingCartItem` entity on `Product` cascade delete?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the following in your builder object

```
builder.Entity<ShoppingCartItem>()
    .HasOne(s => s.Product)
    .WithOne(p => p.ShoppingCartItem)
    .Metadata.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
```

Comment: I have tried this where your have `.WithOne(p => p.ShoppingCartItem)` in your answer, but there is no reference from `ShoppingCartItem` in the `Product` entity. Only the other way around where `Product` entity is referenced in the `ShoppingCartItem`entity. Should `ShoppingCartItem` be referenced in the `Product` entity..? For me it feels unnecessary..

Comment: Maby I should just remove the `Product` entity reference and have a `public int ProductId` instead in the `ShoppingCartItem` entity..

Comment: Isn't it one on one relationship? Try removing the WithOne totally then.

Comment: The following documentations says that you need to declare a reference from the one entity to the other: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/conventions/one-to-one-relationship I would have thought that it should only be needed to define foreignkey relation from "parent" to "child", but not also "child" to "parent" relation..

Comment: Indeed. The one on one should have the reference from both sides